# how to get the image path on image_tab in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have tried this but I am not getting the answer. I have 3 image box. In this 2 image box have images and 1 image box is empty. Now I want to change the image on image_tab event, can any one help me to find this?

```
Uri myfile = new Uri("Images/star.png", UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(myfile);
BitmapImage myimage = new BitmapImage(myfile);
myimage.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
image1.Source = myimage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly `image_tab` is in your case (maybe `Image_Tap`?), but you can simplify your image source assignment by using:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("PATH", UriKind.Relative);
BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
image.Source = imageSource;
```

Remember, that the `ImageSource` object does not expose the path directly, so you might want to have an internal reference location where paths to files you use are handled.

Comment: yes its on Image_Tap, i tried this one also but i am not getting the answer, i just want to get the path of that image and i want to store in one string variable , can u help to find this (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I Find the answer.. Answer is  String 'imagesource = ((BitmapImage)image.Source).UriSource.ToString();'